# Can I mix the use of VAO and direct usage of glVertexAttribPointer?

Tags: opengl, vbo, vertex-buffer, vao

Let's say I am not using VAOs. I have an array of vertex positions in memory that I want to send to the shader. I do the following (assume I have enabled the corresponding vertex attrib arrays):

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertexDataAsFloats);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureData);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, someOtherData);
glDrawArrays(...);
```

This works well and I see the mesh with proper textures. `someOtherData` is sent to the shader correctly as well. Now I decide to put the `vertexDataAsFloats` and `textureData` in `VBOs`:

```
BindVAO(1); // binds the VAO with a handle generated from glGenVertexArrays()
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataBufferObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
UnBindVAO();
```

Later, before drawing:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, someOtherData);
BindVAO(1);
glDrawArrays(...);
UnBindVAO();
```

Can I mix the calls to `glVertexAttribPointer` and `VAO` before the draw call, where `someOtherData` is **not** in a `VBO`? Currently, this approach is not working as I am not receiving valid data for `someOtherData` in the shader.

I realize that `someOtherData` should go in a `VBO` as well and bound with the `VAO`. There is some legacy code that I have to work with which does not use `VBOs`. In any case, I would like to know if the above is legal in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that mixing `VAOs` with `glVertexAttribArray()` calls where the latter does not use a `VBO` does not work and emits no `OpenGL` errors. This means that if you decide to use `VAOs` then all `glVertexAttrbArray()` calls must be made to a corresponding `VBO`.

Answer (score 0):

The gl*Pointer calls will store the currently bound buffer object and use it as the data source no matter what buffer object is bound during glDrawArrays and other draw calls.

So as long as you unbind the buffer object before you call glVertexAttribPointer it will interpret its source argument as an absolute address instead of an offset into a buffer object.

EDIT: apparently it used to be possible because the extension was based on the APPLE VAO extension, but isn't anymore. Refer to the revision history in https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt

I guess nowadays you should really just use streaming with buffer objects in a double buffer setup.

Comment: Just so that I understood correctly, calling `glVertexAttribPointer` with an absolute address before binding a `VAO` and then doing a draw call _should_ work? I am unable to get this to work so I wanted to be absolutely sure so that I look elsewhere in the code for a bug.

Comment: Hmm, I think I found your issue. There seems to be a difference between glVertexPointer and glVertexAttribPointer in this regard.

The docs for glVertexAttribPointer say "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if zero is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER buffer object binding point and the pointer argument is not NULL."

Can you check for this error? AttribPointer was added later when shaders were introduced already.

Comment: That's interesting. If I understand the doc correctly, I should get the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when using an absolute address for the pointer argument unless I have a buffer bound. In my case, I get the invalid operation error only if I bind a `VAO` before calling `glVertexAttribPointer`. The interesting thing is that if I don't use VBOs/VAOs at all and use `glVertexAttribPointer` with an absolute address, the attributes are transferred to the shader correctly. The only time when they don't is when I call `glVertexAttribPointer` and then bind a `VAO` and then make a draw call.

Comment: Apparently it used to be possible in the past to access client memory from VAOs, but it isn't anymore. This is probably because the ARB extension is based on the APPLE extension which allows this. 
In the changelog it states:
"deleted obsolete INVALID_OPERATION on draw with client arrays since it's no longer possible to define a VAOs with client arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for [GL_ARB_vertex_array_object](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt) is clear on this:

> ...client memory cannot be accessed through a non-zero vertex array object...

However, there is a workaround for you here.  You can use use VAOs for everything else, but just bind VAO 0 and then issue the full set of glVertexAttribPointer calls (i.e referencing both buffer objects and client memory) for the legacy part of your code.

Comment: Seems as if it is allowed in Apple's VAO extension however:
"This extension differs from GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object in that client memory cannot be accessed through a non-zero vertex array object."